# how to accept some answers and give votes?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

anyone can give some advice please? sorry, I couldn't work it out

Comment: Belongs on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Take a look at the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: This is [a list of your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/405258/xuanyinwen) Revisit them. To accept an answer as the accepted answer use the tick mark to the left. This will give you +2 rep. When you have enough rep (15 I think) you can upvote helpful answers with the arrow to the left of the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

To accept answers, click on the checkmark beside the answer you want to accept.  To give votes you need more reputation (15 to vote up, 100 to vote down).  The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) is a good place to go for this kind of information.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answers to these questions in the FAQ
https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

There is a more extensive [FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) on accepting answers on this site.